# How do I read the names of files in a directory into an array?

Tags: c#, io

I have a folder C:\MergeMe\ that is full of tab-delimited text files, but the number of files is unknown at any given time.

How do I read and store the names of the text files in the MergeMe directory into an array?

Comment: System.IO.Directory.GetFiles ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(). If you know the extension, you can, for example call:

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\MergeMe\*.txt")
```

If you need other options, there are overloads that allow you to provide them.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles("MyPath"))
        {
            if (Path.GetExtension(file)=="youExtension")
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
                {
                    //Your code
                }
            }
        }
    }
```